# Serum or interferon

Tags: word-request, collocations, image-identification

What the word is  used for object in the picture and which verb is collocated with it?

[image]

Comment: you edited this question and now you are clear about it. Please inform the answerer whenever you edit your question with a major change.

Answer (score 4):

I would call that an IV bag.  IV is short for [Intravenous Therapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intravenous_therapy).

As Maulik says, infuse is probably the best verb, although I would use a different phrase.

> Give him electrolytes intravenously.
>
> Give him electrolytes by IV.

Answer (score 3):

In medical field, we call it as an 'infusion'. The object you see there from where the liquid comes is a 'bottle' made of plastic/glass etc.

For instance, a patient with severe dehydration comes, I may advise the nurse to treat him with the **infusion** of 5% dextrose or whatever.

The verb is infuse.

> Infuse him with electrolytes

---

A major change in the question unbeknownst to me! [I'm removing the 'cartoon' part, it's not relevant now]

Yes, that's an [infusion bag](https://www.google.com/search?q=infusion%20bag&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=SxFLVbeJBtaPuAT38oG4Bw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAg&biw=1920&bih=894)